# PROOF of Only Hot to Cold Heat Transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

We know the results, add water to ice. Ice melts and water cools. How do we PROVE that it is 100% Hot to Cold? The molecules in a hot object are moving faster and will facilitate the transfer of heat to the colder medium. BUT, its molecules are also moving. How do we PROVE it is 100% in one direction and Not 95%/5% or some other ratio until equilibrium is achieved?

Comment: In fact, Until thermodynamic equilibrium is achieved, Molecules/particles collide randomly, Not 100% hot to cold, Instead you cannot define an exact boundry like "This is hot" and "This is cold" in microscopic view as hotness is measured by temperature which is proportional to average kinetic energies of particles, But you can say that particles having more kinetic energy dominate heat transfer from hot to cold temperatures till equilibrium is reached

Comment: Are you familiar with the second la of thermodynamics?

Comment: DG Agreed, It seemed Simplistic to simply say that Heat Flows Hot to Cold without any qualifications to that strict assertion.

Answer (score 1):

The laws of thermodynamics possess a *probabilistic nature*: they are expected to hold on average, but there is nothing to preclude their temporary violation when we go beyond the thermodynamic limit. As thermodynamics typically involves exceptionally large systems, the law of large numbers tells us that the likelihood of observing significant deviations from the average value essentially becomes negligible.

If you are interested in an insightful demonstration of Clausius's statement, take a look at to Section II, titled '*Why Entropy Production Matters*,' in the paper [Irreversible Entropy Production, from Quantum to Classical](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.07668.pdf). At the end of Subsection A, the authors present a compelling argument showing that this statement is valid based on considerations of entropy.

Comment: Very Good Cited Reference. Pages 16 and 17 helped a lot. Maxwell’s Demons. A demon, in this context, has access
to additional information, in the form of global correlations
shared between A and B. These correlations can then be consumed as a thermodynamic resource.
Correlations, of course, will not always make heat flow
from cold to hot. They may very well have the opposite effect,
accelerating the heat from hot to cold.

Comment: @JoeAdams in this regard, it is known that if A and B share a correlation, then the heat flow can reverse, moving from cold to hot. This phenomenon is known as anomalous heat exchange. A nice and recent paper discussing this effect is the following: https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.03828